# Decision rule that minmize the probability of error

Tags: density-function, decision-theory, noise

#### Given

We consider a real-valued, discrete-time communication system with a channel gain $h$ and additive white Laplacian noise of unit scale with two possible signals $s \in (-\mu,+\mu)$ that are sent equiprobably: $y = hs + w$. To be more precise, the noise $W$ has the pdf

\begin{align}
   f_W(w) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|w|}
\end{align}

Further, we define $SNR = \mu$, as a signal-to-noise ratio for noise of unit scale.

#### Question

Suppose first $h = 1$. Specify the decision rule that minimizes the probability of error in deciding on the transmitted message $s$, and compute the average error probability $P_e$ in terms of our definition of SNR.

#### Attempted solution

For $h = 1$ we have that

\begin{align}
   y = s + w
\end{align}

We will have two cases, first for $-\mu$

\begin{align}
   y = -\mu + w \\
   P(y|-\mu) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|w + \mu|}
\end{align}
and call this hypothesis $H_0$

Secondly, for $+\mu$ we will have

\begin{align}
   y = \mu + w \\
   P(y|+\mu) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|w-\mu|}
\end{align}
and this hypothesis is called $H_1$

My question is, do I always have to calculate conditional probability when when calculating the probability of error? And I also wonder that is the equation for the probability of error in this case?

Comment: There is a derivation in the book on the probability of error involving $\delta_{MPE}(y)$, $\pi(i)$, $p(y|i)$, $\pi(0)$, $pi(1)$ but for me it makes no sense, like isn't there any way to do it in like two or three equations?

Answer (score 0):

First question: Yes, When dealing with error probabilities you always have to calculate the conditional probabilities.